# Sockets LAN Multiplayer Issues

Tags: javascript, sockets, networking, websocket, socket.io

Currently making a Multiplayer Game with HTML5 (Phaser) and Eureca.io, up until now i have playing the game on two windows on my computer to test it, yesterday/today i have attempted to play it over my local network with a family member by starting the server on my computer and then on the other persons computer typing my computers ip followed by the port ip:port. But all i get is black window the same size as the phaser game and a 404 error and load of connection refused messages in the console. Having never done this or any lan gaming, what could be causing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Verify your IP address, make sure you're using the local IP if you're on LAN, and the external IP (port forwarded) if you're not on on the same subnet (router)

Comment: Check the firewall settings as well.